# What do I do when a horizontal rod for a popup drain is too short?

Tags: bathroom, sink

My contractor just installed a Delta Arzo Two Handle Widspread Lavatory 3586LF into a Kohler Persuade Curv top and basin lavatory, K-2956-8.

The problem is that the horizontal rod for the popup drain is not long enough to connect to the lifting rod strap. This is because the drain is too far from where the faucet is mounted in the sink.

What is the typical solution to this type of problem?

Comment: How long does the pop-up rod need to be?  I'm sure I've seen some long replacement rods (maybe 1ft?) at Home Depot...

Comment: @Niall: That sounds like a better solution than custom-making one. Is this what you remember seeing? http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xih/R-100557521/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053

Comment: @Doresoom: that and its [cousin](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xgf/R-100185988/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053).  @user898: be sure to bring the original rod to the store so you can compare; they all look alike but can be subtly different.

Comment: @Niall: Great point! I don't know how many times I've gone to HD or Lowes and pushed a screw or other hardware partway through the packaging to make sure it fit. I really need to get one of these: http://www.threadtoolsupply.com/sae-inch-screw-checker.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Niall C. suggested finding a replacement rod that fits. Home depot has a [few](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xih/R-100557521/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) [sizes](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xih/R-100185988/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) on-line, but they may have more in the store. I'd try this solution before custom-making one.

Depending on the design of the horizontal rod, you may be able to replace it with a length of [steel rod](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xih/R-100338145/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) with the same diameter.

From what I can tell of the [parts diagram](http://www.plumbersurplus.com/pdf/Delta_Installation_3586LF-SSMPU.pdf) , you may be able to slide some hardware off of the original rod and back on to your custom cut rod of the same diameter. If the original rod is threaded at one end, you could get a [tap and die set](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xih/R-100352484/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) or see if threaded rod would work.

Comment: Finding a replacement rather that using a coupler sounds like the best solution. I found a delta replacement at Lowes and I will see if that works. Thanks for all the help. I will report back if the solution doesn't end up working.

Answer (score 1):

I found a drain kit at Home Depot that has a plastic L shaped rod connector as part of the kit. The whole thing cost $4.85 so it was a cheap fix. I attached the connector with hose clamps since the rods in the kit were slightly larger than my brushed nickel rods.

Answer (score 1):

they make a horizontal extension ..it's on Amazon I've used two with great success

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this started as an older post but we just had the same problem.  Ordered the Delta Cassidy widespread faucet which comes with the Delta RP26533OB Pop Up Drain Assembly and the horizontal rod was 4" too short to be able to connect with the lift strap.  But luckily thanks to someone else posting a question on the Home Depot user forum, Delta replied with the exact part numbers of all 3 lengths and the size we needed was available on Amazon.  The Delta RP26533OB Pop Up Drain Assembly includes the RP12517 Horizontal Rod that is 6 1/8". We have the RP22828 Horizontal Rod that is 8 1/8" in length and the RP33805 Horizontal Rod that is 10 1/8" in length.

Disappointing that their own product documentation does not detail out the individual part number or even reference the fact that they offer 3 versions of this part with varying lengths - 6.125", 8.125" and 10.125".  Also not sure why they don't have slightly different versions of the faucet so that upon ordering you can get the length you need.  Or make the availability of this part as visible as the mounting deck extension kits.