# Moen: What do I do when a horizontal rod for a popup drain is too short?

Tags: bathroom, sink

Pretty much the same as this question: [What do I do when a horizontal rod for a popup drain is too short?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-do-i-do-when-a-horizontal-rod-for-a-popup-drain-is-too-short)

Can anyone hook me up for what to do for a horizontal rod too short for a Moen setup? My setup: https://postimg.cc/9wwjQgQm

[image]

Only ideas I have is something like this, but slow delivery time: https://a.co/d/1clGQAf

Comment: You use a sink pivot rod extension to extend the horizontal (pivot) rod. As already answered on the linked question. Or a longer rod, as also answered there. Evidently you might also need a lift rod extension.

Comment: I replaced two drains with push to open/close drains.  No connecting rods needed.

Answer (score 2):

Buy another lifting rod strap and a couple of small nuts and bolts.

Bolt them together and the extra thickness will not bend so easily.
Your drain will work just fine.